# Ускорение Сишниго ввода/вывода

Tags: c++, c

Если в программе используется Сишный ввод/вывод (`scanf()`, `printf()`), то рассинхронизация потоков (`std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)`) может увеличить производительность? Или это работает только в обратную сторону?

Comment: Я бы предположил, что не должно влиять.

Answer (score 5):

Не удобства возникнут при запросе у пользователя например имени.

```
# include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
  std::cout<<"Print name:";
  char s[100];
  scanf("%s",s);
  printf("s=%s\n",s); }
```

Сначала запрашивает имя, а потом при закрытии программы только выводит запрос ввода.

В сишной библиотеке есть свой буфер, пусть он и занимается ускорением. А при отключении синхронизации два буфера (C++ и C) будут работать асинхронно.

```
$ ./a.out 
Alex
s=Alex
Print name:
```

На производительность запаздывание вывода на экран никак не влияет. Всё зависит от исполнения консоли в операционной системе.

Comment: ну в любом случае мешать `cout`  и `print/scanf` мне кажется не очень хорошая задумка. А вот если ещё `cin.tie(0)` (есть кстати аналог для `printf`?) то всё ещё интереснее станет.

Comment: _"На производительность запаздывание вывода на экран никак не влияет."_ - неправда.

Answer (score 2):

Да, это может ускорить ввод/вывод в обе стороны.

[If the synchronization is turned off, the C++ standard streams are allowed to buffer their I/O independently, which may be considerably faster in some cases.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio)

[In practical terms, synchronization usually means that a standard iostream object and a standard stdio object share a buffer.](https://eel.is/c++draft/input.output#footnote-289)

Comment: А расскажи подробнее, почему?

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что при синхронизации `iostream` и `stdio` обычно используют один буфер, поэтому каждая операция записи в `iostream` эквивалентна такой же записи в `stdio` и **наоборот**. Без синхронизации они могут использовать разные буферы, за счёт этого может улучшится производительность

Comment: Но кто из них отвечает за синхронизацию? По идее, иострима может вообще не быть, тогда и настраивать нечего. А если его нет, то и без настроек скорость должна бы быть та же, или нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy реализация отвечает. Если иострим не используют, а синхронизация включена, то теоретически может и не происходить синронизация, но по стандарту она должна быть

Comment: Информация по первой ссылке противоречит твоему ответу.

Comment: @Qwertiy какая именно?

Comment: _"In practice, this means that the synchronized C++ streams are unbuffered, and each I/O operation on a C++ stream is immediately applied to the corresponding C stream's buffer. This makes it possible to freely mix C++ and C I/O."_ - только потоки плюсов небуферизированы, про сишные ничего не сказано.

Answer (score 1):

Cудя по [описанию](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio)

> In practice, this means that the synchronized C++ streams are unbuffered, and each I/O operation on a C++ stream is immediately applied to the corresponding C stream's buffer. This makes it possible to freely mix C++ and C I/O.

эта настройка влияет только на I/O из С++ - они становятся небуферизируемыми, а сишные потоки никак не затрагиваются. Да это и логично - ведь если никакой `iostream` не подключать, то сишный ввод-вывод замедляться не должен, а отключать при этом совершенно нечего.

Так что, скорее всего, классичесий ввод-вывод не ускорится из-за изменения `sync_with_stdio`.